# Is there a way to map a condition to th:insert?

Tags: thymeleaf

What I want to display is a collection of objects like

```json
cards: [
  {
    type: "type_0"
    elements: [
      ...
    ]
  }
  ...
]
```

Where `type` should change the produced html. I imagine the following should work

```html
<div th:switch="${card.type}" th:body="${card}">
    <div th:case="type_0"> <div th:insert="card_0"/> </div>
    ...
</div>
```

But is there a way to do the same without adding an extra case for every new card type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a consistent naming scheme, then you can use preprocessing:

```
<div th:insert="${__${card.type}__}"></div>
```

At runtime, Thymeleaf will first do the preprocessing, so it will convert the code to:

```
<div th:insert="${type_0}"></div>
```

Then, the actual template rendering is done, so if there is a fragment called `type_0.html`, it should get inserted.